# PACT.io: Getting Missing requests error and Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden

Tags: javascript, testing, axios, jestjs, pact

I'm using Pact.io to generate contract test in my consumer, but I'm getting the error:

`Missing requests: GET http://localhost:3001/productId/2857?date=2021-05-31`

I configured the instance of the pact to run on port 3001, but I think the requests are not going through there because I'm getting another error:

`Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden at dispatchError`

I already have tryed to use `axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');`

But I still getting Cross origin http://localhost forbidden at dispatchError.

Already tryed to use `jest --env=node` and `"testEnvironment": "node"` but this options breaked my code with:

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined

    > 1 | import { request } from './requests';
```

Can someone help me, please?

My code is:
package.json code:

```
...
"scripts": {
...
"test:consumer": "jest app/tests/contract/consumer/*.test.js --runInBand --setupFiles ./app/tests/helpers/pactSetup.js --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile=./app/tests/helpers/pactTestWrapper.js",

...
}
...
```

**ContractTest_ClientsConsumer.test.js code:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Matchers } from '@pact-foundation/pact';
import { provider } from '../../helpers/pactSetup';
import viewApi from './viewApi';
import config from '../../../../app/config';

const getApiEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3001';
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');

const productDateResponse = { value: 100, day: "2021-05-31" }

describe('Product Date', () => {
  afterEach(() => provider.verify());

  describe('Get Product Value', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const interaction = {
        state: 'check some product value in some day',
        uponReceiving: 'value product in some day',
        withRequest: {
          method: 'GET',
          path: `${config.API_URL}/productId/2857?date=2021-05-31`,
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          },
        },
        willRespondWith: {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          },
          body: Matchers.somethingLike(productDateResponse),
        },
      };
      return provider.addInteraction(interaction);
    });

    test('returns correct body, header and statusCode', () => {
      console.log('Before calling getProduct');
      const response = viewApi.getProduct(2857, '2021-05-31', null);
      console.log('Called getProduct');
      console.log(response);
      console.log('After print response');
      expect(response.headers['content-type']).toBe('application/json; charset=utf-8');
      expect(response.data).toEqual(productDateResponse);
      expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    });
  });
});
```

**viewApi.js code:**

```
import { request } from './requests';
import config from 'config';
import { response } from 'express';

export default class ViewApi {
  static getProduct(productId, date, requestDate = null) {
    try {
      const url = `${config.API_URL}/productId/${productId}`;
      let queryParams = `date=${date}`;

      if (requestDate) {
        queryParams += `&requestDate=${requestDate}`;
      }

      return request(`${url}?${queryParams}`);
  }
}
```

**pactsSetup.js code:**

```
import path from 'path';
import { Pact } from '@pact-foundation/pact';

export const provider = new Pact({
  port: 3001,
  log: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'app/tests/contract/logs', 'mockserver-integration.log'),
  dir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'app/tests/contract/pacts'),
  spec: 2,
  logLevel: 'DEBUG',
  pactfileWriteMode: 'overwrite',
  consumer: 'pwa-store',
  provider: 'api-store',
});
```

**pactTestWrapper.js code:**

```
import { provider } from './pactSetup';

beforeAll(() => provider.setup());

afterAll(() => provider.finalize());
```

I have an environment variable called API_URL that I'm defining with:
`export API_URL=http://localhost:3001`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will have no impact on your `request` object (which I assume is an axios client?) because it happens after the module is loaded, and only applies to the default client.

```
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
```

You might be able to just apply the adapter directly to the `request` client, but worth checking the Axios docs for that.

I think these are your options:

1. Fix your `./request` client so that it is configured with the updated adapter
2. Set `cors: true` on the pact object, so that it will respond with the `OPTIONS` headers as it would if it was being sent over a web app (seems like the default mode)

(2) might make more sense given it's more consistent with your actual usage.